# How can I split a large file with tab-separated values into smaller files while keeping lines together in a single file based on the first value?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have a file (currently about 1 GB, 40M lines), and I need to split it into about smaller files based on a **target file size** (target is ~1 MB per file).

The file contains multiple lines of tab-separated values. The first column has an integer value. The file is sorted by the first column. There are about 1M values in the first column, so each value has on average 40 lines, but some may have 2 and others may have 100 or more lines.

```
12\t...
12\t...
13\t...
14\t...
15\t...
15\t...
15\t...
16\t...
...
2584765\t...
2586225\t...
2586225\t...
```

After splitting the file, any distinct first value must only appear in a single file. E.g. when I read a smaller file and find a line starting with `15`, it is guaranteed that no other files contain lines starting with `15`.

This does **not** mean map all lines that start with a specific value to a single file.

Is this possible with the commandline tools available on a Unix/Linux system?

Comment: Some statistics about the input might help.  How many unique keys might exist in the file? ...

Comment: Some tools that you might want to explore might be `split`, `awk`, `csplit`.

Comment: So the final outcome should be like one file which contains 12,13,14...2586225 and second file corresponding lines. Is this you want.

Comment: What about if a key has too much data mapped to it, so that two files are needed to meet your condition of files being ~ 1MB. Is 1 MB condition mandatory OR the basic requirement would be to split data across multiple files for key values?

Comment: @Jigar No that is not it.

Comment: is each record exactly the same size, close to same size, or highly variable? Good luck.

Comment: Close to the same size

Answer (score 2):

The following will try to split every 40,000 records, but postpone the split if the next record has the same key as the previous.

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { i=1; s=0; f=sprintf("file%05i", i) }
    NR % 40000 == 0 { s=1 }
    s==1 && $1!=k { close(f); f=sprintf("file%05i", ++i); s=0 }
    { k=$1; print >>f }' input
```

Answer (score 0):

List all the keys by looking at only the first column `awk` and making them unique `sort -u`. Then for each of these keys, select only the lines that start with the key `grep` and redirect this into a file named after the key.

Oneliner:

```
for key in `awk '{print $1;}' file_to_split | sort -u` ; do grep -e "^$key\\s" file_to_split > splitted_file_$key ; done
```

Or multiple lines for a script file and better readability:

```
for key in `awk '{print $1;}' file_to_split | sort -u`
do
  grep -e "^$key\\s" file_to_split > splitted_file_$key
done
```

Not especially efficient as it parses the files many times.

Also not sure the `for` command being able to use such a large input from the ``` `` ``` subcommand.

Comment: This is just a rather inefficient reimplementation of `csplit`.

Comment: Also, to avoid the `ARG_MAX` problem, you should convert the `for` loop into a `while` loop.  http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks

Answer (score 0):

On unix systems you also can usually use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). So here is a perl solution:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;

my $last_key;
my $store;
my $c = 0;
my $max_size = 1000000;

while(<>){
    my @fields = split(/\t/);
    my $key  = $fields[0];

    if ($last_key ne $key) {
       store() if (length($store)>$max_size);
    }
    $store.=$_;
    $last_key = $key;        
}
store();

sub store {
    $c++;
    open (O, ">", "${c}.part");
    print O $store;
    close O;
    $store='';
}
```

save it as x.pl.

use it like:

```
x.pl bigfile.txt
```

It sorts your entries into

1.part
   2.part
   ...

files and tries to keep them around $max_size.

HTH